# How can I get test kitchen run same chef recipe multiple times?

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

I have a chef recipe that I'm using for deploying an application. Each time the recipe runs it creates a new "release" (with the current timestamp) directory and deletes older "release" directories leaving only the 5 most recent "release" directories. (similar to how Capistrano's keep_releases works).

To test that functionality I need to run my "deploy" recipe 6 times and verify that there are only 5 "release" directories. It seems that I am not able to have the same recipe in the run_list more than once.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find out how to do it ? I tried answer below (nothing), I tried special recipe that includes default twice (nothing). In both case run_list is merge or resources are merge.

Comment: I found workaround for my case. I am using 'special script' where I am running specific kitchen job in sequence. So in my case, script will: `destroy`, `create`, `converge`, `converge`, `verify` and `destroy`
 - destroy

Comment: @Lukino I was able to get the suggested solution to work.

Comment: unfortunately I wasn't (see comments below). Maybe it is weird setup (too much gems around this) Anyway, [TestKitchen 2.0](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/issues/162) should have this be default without any dirty hacks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2019: use `multiple_converge` as described in https://docs.chef.io/config_yml_kitchen.html**

*Old solution:*

You can use duplicate suite names to converge a node twice (or more times).

e.g. in your .kitchen.yml to run the "default" suite twice:

```
suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[your-cookbook::recipe]
    attributes:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[your-cookbook::recipe]
    attributes:
```

However maybe you want to use [ChefSpec](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec) to test it without having to converge a node each time.

[Tested with test-kitchen 1.4.0 + kitchen-vagrant 0.18.0](https://gist.github.com/rmoriz/de64387cc1b1e3bef45f)

Comment: Your complain neither provided a version number of test-kitchen nor the driver you were using.

Comment: well, you added version just now. i am not complaining just trying to figure out why it is not working as I remember that it was. I will update version tomorrow.

Comment: You claimed my solution was not working. It's your turn to deliver information/proof…

Comment: I had version TK 1.3.1 and KV 0.16.0. After updating to version edited 13h ago, Following
`- name: SSHAccess-2x-run
    data_bags_path: "test/integration/SSHAccess/data_bags"
    run_list:
        - recipe[ssh_access::default]
    attributes: {}
    
  - name: SSHAccess-2x-run
    data_bags_path: "test/integration/SSHAccess/data_bags"
    run_list:
        - recipe[ssh_access::default] 
    attributes: {}`
won't run converging twice when running `kitchen test SSHAccess-2x-run`. Driver=Vagrant, Provider=libvirt. I can't do more thorough check why right now. I will return to this later

Answer (score 3):

There is an option within the provisioner in Test Kitchen now which allows you to run multiple converges.

The provisioner configuration below will tell Chef to converge 3 times:

```
provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  product_name: chef
  deprecations_as_errors: true
  multiple_converge: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use kitchen dokken to test your cookbook, you can simply do 'kitchen converge' again once the node is converged. It is simillar to running chef-client again on converged node.