# block suite 'verify' in 'kitchen test'

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

I'm running 2 different recipes from 2 suites, and both suites have same name so that these recipes would run on same machine. But the problem is, once the test kitchen run with first recipe, it starts to 'verify' the suite, which i don't want to do. I want to run the 'verify' once the both recipes are executed from different chef-client run. Is it possible to block the test-kitchen from doing 'verify' in 'kitchen test'?

Comment: Hi ReshmaA, I'm looking for a little bit of clarity about what you're trying to accomplish before I try to formulate an answer. Are you trying to apply multiple recipes to a machine in sequence then run a verifier against them? Or is there some other reason you must use multiple suites/seperate chef runs?

Comment: Yes,i want to test a s/w install and uninstall recipes.To test uninstall recipe,i shud first apply install recipe to the runlist then in nxt convergence, uninstall recipe. If i apply both recipes on same runlist,uninst recipe wont get executed. Hence i opted multi Chef convergence which is possible as per this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386630/how-can-i-get-test-kitchen-run-same-chef-recipe-multiple-times. The pblm is,after 1st convergence,the test kitchen tries to verify,using the test cases thats written inside the suite specfic test folder,which is for uninstall&fails

Comment: @JackChance : atleast I should be able to change the test path for the suite.

Answer (score 0):

"both suites have the same name" That isn't allowed, whatever you think you're doing, you probably aren't actually doing. I think you're trying to do some kind of multi-converge testing, which Test Kitchen does not currently support.

Comment: You are right Test Kitchen does not currently support multi-converge testing, there are few issues(https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/issues/162 , https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/pull/564  etc) raised on Github on the same and not resolved yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to achieve what you're doing automatically without writing some script to modify the kitchen.yml file, and the link you provided states that the duplicate suite names approach doesn't work.

How, if you want to converge twice on the same node and apply two different recipes with two different test sweets you could run the first converge with the first set of tests, modify the suite in your kitchen.yml with a new run list and test file, then converge again on the same suite. With some work you could even script it so that you can kick this all off with a single command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JackChance, I will think of someway to achieve it.